# Where to find out the table and create column on Azure Management Port?

Tags: azure, xamarin

I used to find the DATA button in management port.

But now the button has been removed from the port, and I cannot find a way to access it anymore and I haven't got the answer from Azure document nor google.

Is there anybody know how to access the table and create column now in Azure?   Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A good tool for accessing your table storage (next to Visual Studio) is [Azure Storage Explorer](http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Although it is out of date.  But thank you for your answer!!!